# iis dynamic ip restriction for specific folder under website

Tags: iis

I have edited the "dynamic restriction settings" for my website and I have set it to deny 5 concurrent requests for the website. But because I want to display custom error pages, I have created an Error folder under website and tried to change its dynamic restriction settings. So I can disable "deny concurrent request" in order to be able to display error page in errors folder.

But when I open "View Dynamic Restriction Settings" for that folder those 2 options are disabled. What is wrong with it? how can I change the dynamic ip restrictions for folder level?

[image]

PS: I have tried to display custom error pages using web.config

I have tried

```
<httpErrors>
    <error statusCode="403" subStatusCode="6" path="/ErrorPage_tooMuchClick.htm" responseMode="ExecuteURL" />
</httpErrors>
```

and

```
<customErrors defaultRedirect="errorpage.htm" mode="RemoteOnly">
  <error statusCode="404" redirect="filenotfound.htm" />
  <error statusCode="403" redirect="ErrorPage_tooMuchClick.htm"  />
</customErrors>
```

but none of them works

Answer (score 1):

I tried to force that configuration via configuration editor  mysite/myfolder  **WebServer/Security/dynamicIpSecurity/DenyByConcurrentRequests/enabled**=**True**.

Then you will see It has been checked.

[image]

However, when I test concurrent requests, it is not working at all.
[image]

So I'm afraid DynamicIPrestriction is not supported in folder level for the time being. You may have to set it in site level.

Comment: thanks for your try and your answer. You are right, it looks it is not possible